# Unable to connect to admin console http://localhost:9393 from xd-shell on mac

Tags: spring-xd

On my mac, I've installed Spring XD-1.2.1.RELEASE and set up XD_HOME as per the instructions found on spring-xd site when I Run the shell command I get error saying:

> server-unknown:>admin config info   -------------  --------------------------------------------------------------   Result         Unable to contact XD Admin Server at 'http://localhost:9393/'-------------  -------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- An exception ocurred during targeting: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:9393/":Connection refused; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Could you tell me if anything special required to be configured. Note: works well in Windows, though.

Answer (score 1):

Did you start your spring xd service ? bin/xd-singlenode from XD_HOME ?

Answer (score 0):

> Connection refused

Means the admin is not running. After starting the admin (or singlenode) enter

```
sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P | grep 9393
```

If you don't see an entry for 9393 look in the admin log to see what happened.